# Relationship between Gram determinant and cross product

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to prove that the determinant of the Gram matrix is equal to the norm of the cross product squared for $v_1, v_2 \in \mathbb{R}^3$:

$$\|v_1 \times v_2\|^2 = \det\Bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
\langle v_1, v_1 \rangle & \langle v_1, v_2 \rangle\\ 
\langle v_2, v_1 \rangle & \langle v_2, v_2 \rangle
\end{smallmatrix}\Bigr)$$

But the only idea I have seems very technical and unpleasant, any suggestions?

I have already seen [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805196/how-to-prove-this-gram-determinant) thread but I don't find it helpful.

Comment: Just use the formulas and do the calculations? It’s worth doing at least once in your life.

Comment: You can also use the formulas that involve the angle between the two vectors.

Comment: This is a special case of [a more general identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3372955) due to probably Lagrange or Sylvester (I forgot who).

Comment: Both sides are the square of the area of the parallelogram spanned by $v_1$ and $v_2$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The identity $(u\times v)\cdot(x\times y)=\begin{vmatrix}u\cdot x&amp;v\cdot x\\ u\cdot y&amp;v\cdot y\\\end{vmatrix}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3372955/the-identity-u-times-v-cdotx-times-y-beginvmatrixu-cdot-xv-cdot-x-u-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a straightforward argument without horrendous algebra. Assume $v_1,v_2$ are linearly independent; I leave the degenerate case to you. Let $n=\dfrac{v_1\times v_2}{\|v_1\times v_2\|}$. Consider the matrix
$$A = \left[\begin{array}{ccc} | & | & | \\ v_1 & v_2 & n \\ | & | & |\end{array}\right].$$
Then your Gram determinant is the determinant of $A^\top A$. On the other hand, $\det (A^\top A) = \det (A^\top)\det(A) = \det(A)^2$. But
$$\det A = n\cdot (v_1\times v_2) = \|v_1\times v_2\|.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\def\e{\varepsilon}\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}$
The [Levi-Civita symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol) allows one to write the cross product as
$$\eqalign{
c &= a\times b \\&= \e:ab^T \\
c_i &= \e_{ijk}\;a_jb_k\quad\big({\rm index\,notation}\big) \\
}$$
where the colon denotes the double-dot product.
The symbol has another interesting property
$$\eqalign{
\e_{ijn}\,\e_{nk\ell}
  &= \delta_{ik}\,\delta_{j\ell} - \delta_{i\ell}\,\delta_{jk}
\quad\big({\rm Kronecker\,delta\,symbols}\big) \\
  &= \alpha_{ijk\ell}-\beta_{ijk\ell} \\
\e\cdot\e &= \alpha-\beta \\
}$$
The fourth-order tensors $(\alpha,\beta)$ have some useful and easily verified properties.

Given an arbitrary matrix $(M)$
$$\eqalign{
\alpha:M &= M:\alpha &= M\qquad&\big({\rm identity\,operation}\big) \\
\beta:M &= M:\beta &= M^T\qquad&\big({\rm transpose\,operation}\big) \\
}$$
Putting all of this together
$$\eqalign{
(a\times b)\cdot(f\times g)
 &= (ab^T:\e)\cdot(\e:fg^T) \\
 &= ab^T:(\e\cdot\e):fg^T \\
 &= ab^T:(\alpha-\beta):fg^T \\
 &= (ab^T:\alpha:fg^T) - (ab^T:\beta:fg^T) \\
 &= (ab^T:fg^T) - (ab^T:gf^T) \\
 &= (a\cdot f)(b\cdot g) - (a\cdot g)(b\cdot f) \\
 &= \det\left(\m{a\cdot f&a\cdot g\\b\cdot f&b\cdot g}\right)\\
}$$
Now set $\;(a=f=v_1)\;$ and $\;(b=g=v_2)\;$ to obtain the desired result.