# cross product identity and determinant

Tags: linear-algebra

$\newcommand\span[1]{\langle #1 \rangle}$
Is there a connection between the $$ || a \times b|| $$ and the determinant

$$\det \begin{pmatrix}\span{a,a} & \span{a,b} \\ \span{b,a} & \span{b,b} \end{pmatrix} \ \  ?$$

If so how can I prove this? Thank you

Comment: yes sir, im not usre what went wrong and the latex didn't work. thank you

Comment: Are the angle brackets supposed to be the dot product? You should write `\langle, \rangle` to render $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$

Comment: Hint: Parallelogram Law

Comment: See [https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3372955](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3372955).